# Capistrano with PHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a helloworld site from my local machine to a server. I have installed Ruby, Rails and Capistrano. After having a recipe I type this "cap deploy:setup" command and get following error

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:122:in
>   `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`primary' for
>
> ## (NameError)   from ./config/deploy.rb:19:in `load'    from
>
> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in
>   `load_from_file'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in`load'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in`each'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'    from Capfile:4:in`load'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in
>   `load_from_file'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in`load'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in`each'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in`
>   load_recipes'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in
>   `each'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in`
>   load_recipes'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:30:in
>   `execute!'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in`
>   execute'     from /usr/bin/cap:4

Following is my deploy.rb file contents.

```
set :application, "testapp"
set :repository,  "<url of git repo>"
set :deploy_to, "var/www/html/testapp"
set :document_root, "var/www/html/testapp/current"

set :scm, :git
set :scm_username, "MyUserName"
set :scm_password, "MyPassword"
set :scm_checkout, "clone"
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

set :user, "<server's user name>"
set :password, "<server's password>"
set :use_sudo, false
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}

role :web, "<server's IP>"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "<server's IP>"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "<server's IP>", primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
# if you're still using the script/reapear helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# namespace :deploy do
#   task :start {}
#   task :stop {}
#   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
#     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
#   end
# end
namespace :deploy do
    task :update do
        transaction do
            update_code
            symlink
        end
    end

    task :finalize_update do
        transaction do          
        end
    end

    task :symlink do
        transaction do
            run "ln -nfs #{current_release} #{deploy_to}/#{current_dir}"
            run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/#{current_dir} #{document_root}"
        end
    end

    task :migrate do
    end

    task :restart do
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 role :db,  "<server's IP>", primary => true
```

Should be

```
 role :db,  "<server's IP>", :primary => true
```